# Is the code `<script src="show.js"></script>` dangerous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A software developer created a web page for us and added the following code at the very bottom of the page:

```
<script src="show.js"></script>
```

Is this code dangerous for us to add to our web page? Is there a legitimate reason for the developer to add the above code, and if so what is the purpose of this code?

Comment: It should not, but depend on what code you have inside `show.js`

Comment: This is akin to asking, "Does this box contain anything harmful?", without allowing us to look inside the box.

Comment: The rest of the code that the developer gave us looks clean and safe. However, we have not seen the above code before so we were wondering if the above code is dangerous to add to a web page that has JavaScript? What is the purpose of the above code?

Comment: The show.js file only has the following one line of code: echo.init();   Is this code also dangerous and what is its purpose? Thank you!

Comment: @BermudaGirl The `echo` "module" with the `init` "function" has been previously defined. What does that do? Anyway, putting a <script> at the end of the page is one method - although somewhat antiquated / not the most modern - to "run some JS when the HTML is finished parsing". Honestly, if trusting (aka hiring) a developer, you're in for the entire pound (100 pence): this would be one of the 'less sneaky' ways to be malicious, especially as it requires that *other* JavaScript has already executed. If you're not confident, hire a different developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how you would incorporate a JavaScript file with the filename `show.js`.

JavaScript is an essential part of most websites and required for any interactivity (aside from standard hyperlinks and forms). Open the `show.js` file in a text editor to see what the script does.

Comment: The rest of the code that the developer gave us looks clean and safe. However, we have not seen the above code before so we were wondering if the above code is dangerous to add to a web page that has JavaScript. What is the purpose of the above code?    
The show.js file only has the following one line of code: echo.init(); Is this code also dangerous and what is its purpose? Thank you!

Comment: @BermudaGirl It looks like that line initializes an image lazy-loading script called [Echo.js](https://github.com/toddmotto/echo), which allows images to load automatically as they appear on-screen to save users time and bandwidth.

Comment: Hello Jon Uleis: Thank you for your comments and help. That seems about right since images appearing on the page is what we requested from the developer. Thus, can we assume that the echo.init(); code is safe?

Comment: @BermudaGirl Yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes

Comment: Hello Jon Uleis: Thank you for your comments and help! We are new to this website. How can we leave you positive feedback?

Comment: @BermudaGirl Thanks! Just click the checkmark icon next to my answer to accept it and close the question.

Comment: Thank you Jon Uleis. We accepted your answer. Have a wonderful evening!